# Search specific entries in database

Tags: macros, expl3, datatool

I have written a command, which takes five arguments to interpolate between two points.

Now I tried to get the two points from an `csv` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{tempdatabb.dat}
10 & 100
20 & 130
30 & 150
40 & 170
50 & 190
60 & 210
70 & 250
80 & 290
90 & 350
100 & 410
120 & 550
140 & 690
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \ifinstr \tl_if_in:nnTF
\DeclareRobustCommand*\assignvalues[2]{\@assignvalues{#1}{#2}}
\long \def\@assignvalues#1#2{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { | } {#1}
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpb_seq { | } {#2}
  \seq_mapthread_function:NNN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpb_seq \assignvalues@ii
}
\long \def \assignvalues@ii #1#2 { \protected@csedef{#1}{#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\assignvalues{suchwert}{35}

\DTLsetseparator{&}
\DTLloaddb[keys={temperatur,dichte},noheader]{scoreAA {tempdatabb.dat}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llr}
\bfseries Temperatur & \bfseries Dichte %
\DTLforeach[\DTLislt{\temperatur}{\suchwert}]{scoreAA}%
{\temperatur=temperatur,\dichte=dichte}{%
\\\temperatur & \dichte 
}%
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to get the points `(30,150)` and `(40,170)` in four variables as assignment like:

```
\assignvalues{firstx}{30}
\assignvalues{firsty}{150}
\assignvalues{secondx}{40}
\assignvalues{seconxy}{170}
```

But the MWE does not work because of

```
\DTLforeach[\DTLislt{\temperatur}{\suchwert}]{scoreAA}%
```

If I use

```
\DTLforeach[\DTLislt{\dichte}{\suchwert}]{scoreAA}%
```

it works as MWE.

Any ideas about this task?

This question has been asked @ http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?t=74920 
(German).

Some more Examples about the input/output relation

Function (input/output)

```
%Example 1
%Input:

\assignvalues{suchwert}{35}

%Output:

\assignvalues{firstx}{30}
\assignvalues{firsty}{150}
\assignvalues{secondx}{40}
\assignvalues{seconxy}{170}


%Example 2
%Input:

\assignvalues{suchwert}{85}

%Output:

\assignvalues{firstx}{80}
\assignvalues{firsty}{290}
\assignvalues{secondx}{90}
\assignvalues{seconxy}{350}


%Example 3
%Input:

\assignvalues{suchwert}{105}

%Output:

\assignvalues{firstx}{100}
\assignvalues{firsty}{410}
\assignvalues{secondx}{120}
\assignvalues{seconxy}{550}



%Example 4
%Input:

\assignvalues{suchwert}{100}

%Output:

\assignvalues{firstx}{100}
\assignvalues{firsty}{410}
\assignvalues{secondx}{120}
\assignvalues{seconxy}{550}
```

EDITED: More Information

@Steven B. Segletes : Here you can see the work which was led to my question. As you can see, I am going to interpolate between to points, as you also can see, I use \assignvalues to make an variable to more values. This assignment code was originally written by Clemens (look @ http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?t=73700&page=2&highlight=Goldnas) also as the question was set here. Maybe you can now see, what the goal is?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \ifinstr \tl_if_in:nnTF
\DeclareRobustCommand*\assignvalues[2]{\@assignvalues{#1}{#2}}
\long \def\@assignvalues#1#2{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { | } {#1}
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpb_seq { | } {#2}
  \seq_mapthread_function:NNN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpb_seq \assignvalues@ii
}
\long \def \assignvalues@ii #1#2 { \protected@csedef{#1}{#2} }

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\fpeval}{om}
  {
    \IfValueTF {#1}
      { \fp_to_tl:n { round(#2,#1) } }
      { \fp_to_tl:n {#2} }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand {\geraden } {r[]r[]}
{
\assignvalues{nachkommastellen}{3}
\assignvalues{#1}{#2}
\fp_set:Nn \kgerade {(\by - \ay) / (\bx - \ax) } % Lineare 
\fp_set:Nn \dgerade {\by - (\bx * \kgerade)}  % Lineare 
\fp_set:Nn \ygesucht {\dgerade + \kgerade * \gesucht}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|L{3.55cm}|L{2.55cm}|L{2.55cm}|} \hline
\textbf{Punkt} & \textbf{X-Koordinate} & \textbf{Y-Koordinate} \\ \hline
Punkt\  1 & \fpeval[\nachkommastellen]{\ax } & \fpeval[\nachkommastellen]{\ay } \\ \hline
\textit{Gesuchter\ Punkt} & \textit{ \fpeval[\nachkommastellen]{\gesucht }} &   \textit{\fpeval[\nachkommastellen]{\ygesucht }} \\ \hline
Punkt\  2 & \fpeval[\nachkommastellen]{\bx } & \fpeval[\nachkommastellen]{\by } \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\geraden[ax|ay|bx|by|gesucht][20|190|30|150|22]

%The Question which has to be solved is, that I can Call first

%fst: \determinevalues{22} => Should give =Pax,Pay,Pbx,Pby.

%secondly I want to call:

\assignvalue{suchwert}{22}
%\geraden[ax|ay|bx|by|gesucht][\pax|\pay|\pbx|\pby|\suchwert]

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to achieve: with that `\DTLforeach` cycle you're just printing a table.

Comment: @egreg i dont need an table, thats only a way that i can see the data....the relevant thing is, that I can make the 4 assignmentscommands.... no table neccessary....

Comment: What's the role of the database, then?

Comment: The database has the content. I have written a function which calculates the k,d Parameters of the equation y=kx+d from P1(x,y) and P2(x,y). I get P3(x,y), x is the value which is given, y should be calculated. y3=k*x3+d. The two Points should be extracted from the database. The Points should be taken from the database. The smaller one, the bigger on.... calculation the linear equation, interpolate y.... the database contains alle the x,y tuppels of temperature and densitiy for example.....

Comment: for example: database contains the data from MWE. I need an corresponding value to 35 degree of temperatur. But there is no entry for 35 degree. only 30 or 40. I take 30,150 and 40,170... calculate the linear equation and take 35... in this case....it would be y = 35*k + d..... you know what I mean?`I hope so....

Comment: This question was also asked on my [datatool bug tracker](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/bugtracker.cgi?action=view&key=23) where I've answered the reason why your MWE gives a LaTeX error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to address just your concern about extracting individual elements from a data array, I propose the `readarray` package.  It can take either a `\def` or a space-separated data file and stuff the data into either a 2-D or 3-D data array, which can be recalled element by element.

In this latest edit, I put out a string that has what I think are the desired `\assignvalues`.  It is not clear to me though whether this is what the user desires, or for me to actually create a command assignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\def\dataB{%
10  100
20  130
30  150
40  170
50  190
60  210
}
\def\firstx#1{\Arrayij{#1}{\suchrow}{1}}
\def\firsty#1{\Arrayij{#1}{\suchrow}{2}}
\def\secondx#1{\Arrayij{#1}{\suchrowp}{1}}
\def\secondy#1{\Arrayij{#1}{\suchrowp}{2}}
\newcounter{index}
\newcounter{rowvalue}
\newcounter{testvalue}
\newcommand\suchwert[2]{%
  \setcounter{index}{0}%
  \setcounter{testvalue}{#2}
  \whiledo{\value{index} < \csname#1ROWS\endcsname}{%
    \addtocounter{index}{1}%
    \edef\tmp{\csname#1X\roman{index}Xi\endcsname}%
    \setcounter{rowvalue}{\tmp}%
    \ifthenelse{\value{rowvalue} > \value{testvalue}}%
    {\edef\suchrowp{\arabic{index}}%
     \addtocounter{index}{-1}%
     \edef\suchrow{\arabic{index}}%
     \setcounter{index}{\csname#1ROWS\endcsname}%
    }
    {\def\suchrow{NOT-FOUND}}
  }
  \bs assignvalues\{firstx\}\{\firstx{dB}\}\\
  \bs assignvalues\{firsty\}\{\firsty{dB}\}\\
  \bs assignvalues\{secondx\}\{\secondx{dB}\}\\
  \bs assignvalues\{secondy\}\{\secondy{dB}\}\\
}
\def\bs{\ttfamily\char'134}
\parindent 0in
\begin{document}
%   Instead of the \def\dataB above, you can read from a 
%   space-separated data file into \dataB with the 
%   following command:
%\readdef{tempdatab.dat}{\dataB}
\readArrayij{\dataB}{dB}{2}

\suchwert{dB}{35}

\suchwert{dB}{55}

\suchwert{dB}{45}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello,

Sorry, but this solution wont solve the problem. I will try to show input/output examples. Maybe this is then more clear. Your example is based on the knowledge, that I exactly know, row and columm. But row and columm has to be determined by the suchwert. Thats the dynamic problem, which is the main task to solve. I have edited the question for more details.

Comment: As you can see at my post, i am searching for the minimum distanz between to points. I cant see, that you search for 35 (for example), I dont understand the line  \def\firstx#1{\Arrayij{#1}{3}{1}}. What is the meaning of {3}, what  is the meaning of {1}?

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger Does this attempt get closer to what you seek?  I introduced a command `\suchwert` {search word} to decide what row of the array to begin on.  Then, the first and second x,y commands are defined in terms of that.

Comment: Yes. much closer, the last problem that I now have to solve is, that its absolutely necessary to use the assignvalue command. Then its perfect.... :)

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger I don't quite understand how `\assignvalues` is used.  Are firstx etc counters?  Strings?  Is the command supposed to output a number, store a value?  Do I create the command?  Is it pre-existing?

Comment: it is preexisting. As you can see at the first post. I use it to parse more variables, i have massivle used this comand (for example) \assignvalues{A|B|C|D|E}{4|3|2|90|100} givs \A (Displays 4) \B  (Displays 3) and so on. I can calculate with these values, and I have to...

Comment: B. Seglets: It does not work, but I have tried to explain more in detail the goal of the Task. I have answerd to my original post, where more piece of code will be shown to describe, what the problem is. This piece of code works very well, but its only part of the solution. As you can see, some lines are commented. Hopefully it will be enough to describe the problem... best regards Peter

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger it sounds like you want the `\assignvalues` command executed instead of output.  I don't have those packages available to me at the moment, but you can convert my "output" into a command by changing, for example, `\bs assignvalues\{secondy\}\{\secondy{dB}\}` into `\csname assignvalues\endcsname{secondy}{\secondy{dB}}`

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger Not that it was wrong, but don't know why I suggested `\csname assignvalues\endcsname{secondy}{\secondy{dB}}` instead of the more simply written `\assignvalues{secondy}{\secondy{dB}}`

Comment: I dont Know why the much more simply way did not work yesterday. Maybe its an outdated version of my latex. In any case it works now, I have to thank you very much.